# Fraction Problem. 3rd grader question got parents thinking

Tags: probability, combinatorics, normal-distribution

So our nine year old son comes home from 3rd grade and tells us an **amazing** thing happened in school today. He was playing a math game with his friend and they got the same score two times in a row!

Here was the game:

> Deck of 32 cards, each card is blank on front side and has a fraction $\frac{1}{N}$ on the backside, i.e. $\{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}..., \frac{1}{32}\}$. No fraction is repeated. Two players, cards are shuffled, deck is divided into half for each player. It's like [War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_%28card_game%29).  In every round each player plays his top card (random).  Whichever player has a bigger fraction takes both cards and sets them aside. After 16 rounds players count the cards they won. Whoever has more cards wins the game.
>
> Our nine year old thought it was amazing that he and his partner both had 16 cards at the end of the game.

- The question is, using nothing fancier than algebra, what are the odds that both players end up with the same number of cards after one game (16 hands).
- The more interesting question is how to explain the answer to a 3rd grader!

Comment: A short, extremely informal explanation: *Two randoms are still a random* , that is, the probability of getting a particular card on the top of your deck is still equal for each card. Since every outcome is equally probable and different, the probability of winning a particular play is still $1/2$. So there are $\binom{16}{n}$ equally probable ways to have $n$ wins. Can you work from there?

Comment: Actually, the hardest part is the second one.

Answer (score 2):

The fractions don't matter, only that the cards are ordered in strength and there are no ties.  Each player will end with $16$ cards if they each win $8$ rounds.  As the rounds are independent, the chance of this is ${16 \choose 8}\frac 1{2^{16}}=\frac {16!}{8!8!2^{16}} \approx 19.64\%$  You could see [Wikipedia on the central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) and [this Alpha calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16!/8!/8!/2%5E16) of the result.

Comment: This is correct, but not very accessible. Unfortunately, I cannot see any way around it without introducing some equivalently complex computations.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact(where events X and Y are defined suitably) that P(X < Y) = 1/2 = P(X > Y)
(since here, X=Y is not a possibility, the fractions being distinct).